# I get "TypeError: a is undefined" when I try to load specific VTK file

Tags: javascript, three.js, gis, vtk

I try to load VTK file using three.js, I have changed only one line in [example file](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_vtk):

```
loader.load( "models/vtk/srtm.vtk" );
```

[Here is my VTK file.](http://pastebin.com/9TLdR5kx) There is TIN vector map, prepared in GRASS GIS, and converted using v.out.vtk command.

I am very new in Three.js and 3D Graphics, I just want to check some possibilities of Three.js for further work.

Comment: It says "a" is undefined, so where is "a"?

Comment: Hello! I have no idean what is a's role here.
This is from Firebug (Firefox):
   TypeError: a is undefined
   ...his.y+=a.y;this.z+=a.z;return this},addScalar:function(a){this.x+=a;this.y+=a;th...
   three.min.js (line 37)

And this is from Firefox's debugger:
    not well-formed srtm.vtk:1
    TypeError: a is undefined three.min.js:37
    Error in parsing value for 'height'.  Declaration dropped. my_webgl_loader

Comment: If you are debugging, use the non-minified version of three.js, not three.min.js.