# Loading MayaVI VTK into Threejs

Tags: three.js, vtk, mayavi

I'm trying to load a vtk file into three.js that I'm exporting from python using mayaVI. Here's a basic example to produce the vtk (scaled to similar size as the bunny example):

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

x = np.array([0, 0.01])
y = np.array([0, 0.01])
z = np.array([0, 0])

nx = np.array([0, 0])
ny = np.array([0, 0])
nz = np.array([0.04, 0.04])

pts = mlab.quiver3d(x, y, z, nx, ny, nz, mode='cylinder', scale_factor=1)
mlab.show()
pts.module_manager.source.save_output('2cyl_z.vtk')
```

I've been playing around with the example vtk loader: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_vtk but with no success. A simpler version with one cylinder didn't work either.

Logging the geometry object after loading with three.js shows that it has attributes, but they don't seem to contain anything.

If instead I create a true mesh cylinder in mayavi:

```
r = 1.0
pi = np.pi
cos = np.cos
sin = np.sin
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0.1:pi-0.1:101j, 0:2 * pi:101j]

x = r * cos(theta)
y = r * sin(theta)
z = r * cos(phi)

scal = np.ones((101, 101))

mesh = mlab.mesh(x, y, z, scalars=scal)
mlab.show()
mesh.module_manager.source.save_output('mesh_cyl.vtk')
```

It seems to load things into the geometry and I can see the values in the console, but I get this error:

`glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0`

There seems to have been a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941888/i-get-typeerror-a-is-undefined-when-i-try-to-load-specific-vtk-file) that was never resolved.

Comment: Yes, that loader needs some love. Here's some info... https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5609

Comment: Thanks @mrdoob... It seems xtk has this mostly figured out, but I can't use that for other reasons.
https://github.com/xtk/X/blob/master/io/parserVTK.js